# Conda Create TypeError('LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be string, not unicode',)

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

For some reason, I can no longer create conda environments. I have previously created py36 and py34 environments on this machine, but now when I try to create a py37 environment:

```
conda create -n py37 python=3.7 anaconda
```

I get this error after it fails to Download and Extract any Packages:

```
CondaMultiError: TypeError('LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be string, not unicode',)
```

Not sure what's going on. Help appreciated.